# Error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I keep having an error when I click on the last cell of my tableview, It says that I'm accessing something beyond bonds but I can't figure out which array I'm using wrong. It works correctly when I click on other cells it's only the last one with the problem. I think the error comes from my prepareforsegue method. I've put breakpoints everywhere but the error occurs when it exits the prepareforsegue method.

I'm receiving a json file from a web service that I parse and put into a tableview. When the user clicks on a cell I push to a another viewcontroler using a segue from my storyboard, I send the information to this new viewcontroller and display it to the user. I used the same logic and almost identical methods in a previous project and it was working fine.

This is my error :

```
2015-09-22 09:39:07.900 Deblocage[4745:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0078c1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0050b8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0072d3f6 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 246
    3   Deblocage                           0x0004df2e -[JournalDesCommandesPBViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] + 1726
    4   UIKit                               0x00f57efa -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 156
    5   UIKit                               0x00f57f87 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    6   UIKit                               0x00add965 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1453
    7   UIKit                               0x00addb14 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 279
    8   UIKit                               0x00ae210e __38-[UITableView touchesEnded:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 43
    9   UIKit                               0x00a110aa ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
    10  UIKit                               0x00a11055 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403
    11  UIKit                               0x00a10e76 _afterCACommitHandler + 532
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0075436e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x007542bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00732254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x007319d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x007317eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x02a4a5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x02a4a42b GSEventRun + 104
    19  UIKit                               0x009f3f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    20  Deblocage                           0x0004e67a main + 138
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0267e6d9 start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This is my class :

```
#import "JournalDesCommandesPBViewController.h"
#import "Constantes.h"
#import "JournalDesCommandesPBTableViewCell.h"
#import "JournalDesCommandesDetailViewController.h"

@interface JournalDesCommandesPBViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *nomClient;
    NSMutableArray *numCommandeType;
    NSMutableArray *site;
    NSMutableArray *modeCmdQualiteNat;
    NSMutableArray *dateSaisie;
    NSMutableArray *datePrevue;
    NSMutableArray *qualiteDesc;
    NSMutableArray *poids;
    NSMutableArray *montant;
}


@property (nonatomic, strong) id jsonArray;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;

@end

@implementation JournalDesCommandesPBViewController

@synthesize jsonArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableData setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableData setDataSource:self];

    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.tableData addSubview:self.refreshControl];

    [self.tableData reloadData];

}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO] ;
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    [self refreshData];
    // self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}


//refresh data
-(void) refreshData
{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *ID_CLIENT = [defaults objectForKey:@"ID_CLIENT"];

    [self.connection cancel];

    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.receivedData = data;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postData = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"listeCommande\",\"%@,;-1,;PB,;-1",ID_CLIENT];
    [request setValue:@"application/raw; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    self.connection = connection;

    [connection start];

}


// télecharger data

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *e = nil;

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

    NSDictionary *tempJson = jsonArray;

    NSString *firstId =jsonArray[0][@"idCmd"];

    nomClient = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    numCommandeType = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    site = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    modeCmdQualiteNat = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    dateSaisie = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    datePrevue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    qualiteDesc = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    poids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    montant = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *tempId = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempId addObject:firstId];

    NSString *tempNomClient = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)",jsonArray[0][@"nomClient"],jsonArray[0][@"codeClient"]];
    NSString *tempNumCommandeType = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",jsonArray[0][@"numCommande"], jsonArray[0][@"typeCommande"]];
    NSString *tempSite = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",jsonArray[0][@"site"]];
    NSString *tempModeCommandeQualiteNat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",jsonArray[0][@"modeCmd"],jsonArray[0][@"qualiteNat"]];
    NSString *tempDateSaisie = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Saisie le : %@",jsonArray[0][@"dateSaisie"]];
    NSString *tempDatePrevue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Prevue le : %@",jsonArray[0][@"datePrevue"]];
    NSString *tempQualiteDesc = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",jsonArray[0][@"qualiteDesc"]];
    NSString *tempPoids = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",jsonArray[0][@"quantite"],jsonArray[0][@"uMesure"]];

    NSString *tempMontant = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",jsonArray[0][@"montant"]];

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSString *montant_data = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)tempMontant]];
    montant_data = [montant_data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@" "];


    [nomClient addObject:tempNomClient];
    [numCommandeType addObject:tempNumCommandeType];
    [site addObject:tempSite];
    [modeCmdQualiteNat addObject:tempModeCommandeQualiteNat];
    [dateSaisie addObject:tempDateSaisie];
    [datePrevue addObject:tempDatePrevue];
    [qualiteDesc addObject:tempQualiteDesc];
    [poids addObject:tempPoids];



    // YES YES YES
    for (int i = 1; i < (unsigned long)tempJson.count; i++) {

        NSString *idCmd_data = jsonArray[i][@"idCmd"];

        if (![tempId containsObject:idCmd_data] )
        {
            [tempId addObject:idCmd_data];

            tempNomClient = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)",jsonArray[i][@"nomClient"],jsonArray[i][@"codeClient"]];
            tempNumCommandeType = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",jsonArray[i][@"numCommande"], jsonArray[i][@"typeCommande"]];
            tempSite = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",jsonArray[i][@"site"]];
            tempModeCommandeQualiteNat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",jsonArray[i][@"modeCmd"],jsonArray[i][@"qualiteNat"]];
            tempDateSaisie = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Saisie le : %@",jsonArray[i][@"dateSaisie"]];
            tempDatePrevue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Prevue le : %@",jsonArray[i][@"datePrevue"]];
            NSString *tempQualiteDesc = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",jsonArray[i][@"qualiteDesc"]];
            NSString *tempPoids = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",jsonArray[i][@"quantite"],jsonArray[0][@"uMesure"]];

            tempMontant = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",jsonArray[i][@"montant"]];

            NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
            [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
            NSString *montant_data = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)tempMontant]];
            montant_data = [montant_data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@" "];

            /*
             format date : dd/MM/yyyy
            tempDateSaisie = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",jsonArray[i][@"dateSaisie"]];
            NSArray *temp  = [tempDateSaisie componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
            tempDateSaisie = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Saisie le : %@/%@/%@", temp[2], temp[1], temp[0]];
            */

            [nomClient addObject:tempNomClient];
            [numCommandeType addObject:tempNumCommandeType];
            [site addObject:tempSite];
            [modeCmdQualiteNat addObject:tempModeCommandeQualiteNat];
            [dateSaisie addObject:tempDateSaisie];
            [datePrevue addObject:tempDatePrevue];
            [qualiteDesc addObject:tempQualiteDesc];
            [poids addObject:tempPoids];
            [montant addObject:montant_data];
        }
    }


    [self.tableData reloadData];

    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"connection error = %@" , error);
}




// tableData methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return (nomClient.count);
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    JournalDesCommandesPBTableViewCell *customCell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        customCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.929 green:0.941 blue:0.937 alpha:1];
    } else {
        customCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }

    if (customCell == nil)
    {
        customCell = [[JournalDesCommandesPBTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //NSLog(@"Nom Client : %d - %@", nomClient.count , nomClient[0]);


    if (nomClient.count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nomClient.count; i++) {

        }
    }

    customCell.customNom.text = [nomClient objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    customCell.customSite.text = [site objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    customCell.customNumCommandeType.text = [numCommandeType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    customCell.customModeCmdQualiteNat.text = [modeCmdQualiteNat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    customCell.customDatePrevue.text = [datePrevue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    customCell.customDateSaisie.text = [dateSaisie objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return customCell;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)homeTapped:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"JournalDesCommandesPBToAccueil" sender:self];
}


-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    //NSLog(@"%@", [numCommandeType objectAtIndex:5]);
    NSLog(@"%d -- %@",numCommandeType.count ,[numCommandeType objectAtIndex:6]);

    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableData indexPathForSelectedRow];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"JournalToDetail"] && nomClient.count > (path.row))
    {
        NSLog(@"%d", path.row);
        JournalDesCommandesDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        destViewController.nomClientS = [nomClient objectAtIndex:path.row];
        destViewController.numCommandeTypeS = [numCommandeType objectAtIndex:path.row];
        destViewController.siteS = [site objectAtIndex:path.row];
        destViewController.modeCmdQualiteNatS = [modeCmdQualiteNat objectAtIndex:path.row];
        destViewController.dateSaisieS = [dateSaisie objectAtIndex:path.row];
        destViewController.datePrevueS = [datePrevue objectAtIndex:path.row];
        destViewController.poidsS = [poids objectAtIndex:path.row];
        destViewController.qualiteDescS = [qualiteDesc objectAtIndex:path.row];
        destViewController.montantS = [montant objectAtIndex:path.row];

    }
}
```

Edit : 
Crash statement from Xcode : `destViewController.montantS = [montant objectAtIndex:path.row];`

Comment: Which is the statement at which the crash occurs? Also, please provide the  logged statements before the crash.

Comment: please check value for `nomClient.count > (path.row)` & `indexPathForSelectedRow `

Comment: @Ishanhanda It crashes on the last line of prepareforsegue : `destViewController.montantS = [montant objectAtIndex:path.row];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an all objective C exception breakpoint in Xcode and you will see where the crash is. More info about how to add it can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)

Comment: It crashes on the last line of prepareforsegue :  `destViewController.montantS = [montant objectAtIndex:path.row];`

Comment: The obvious thing would be to add an NSLog statement that shows montant.count and path.row.

Comment: There you go, the montantS array doesn't have an object at the index of the path.row.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes and it gives me the same number

Comment: That's the problem, the index of the array starts from 0, so if the count is 5 you have the indexes from 0 to 4.

Comment: @Istvan montantS is a string, I found the error though. I forgot to add the first montant_data to montant. Thanks I didn't know about the exception breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes of arrays are zero-based

```
for (int i = 0; i < (unsigned long)tempJson.count; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't do it